# Would a Beit Din open its proceedings with the recitation of Shehecheyanu?

Tags: beit-din-court, shehecheyanu

I have never been present at a Beit Din, but recently came across a fictional representation of one (for the sake of explanation, let's say it was in a film or television program) that struck me as inauthentic, not least because they opened with the recitation of Shehecheyanu.  Is that a thing?

Comment: I've never heard of it

Comment: I’ve been to Beis Din numerous times. Never heard of such a thing

Comment: What was the Shehecheyanu blessing on? A new fruit? Or simply for the sake of opening up the session? If the latter, it is for sure inaunthentic

Comment: It was recited as an opening prayer.